# sql/Mysql: What is the best method to complete this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I had most of this query worked about except two things, large things, one, as soon as I add the forth table [**departments_tbl**]into the query, I get about 8K rows returned when I should only have about 100.

See the attached schema, no the checkmarks, these are the fields I want returned.

This won't help, but here is just one of the queries that I almost had working, until the [department_tbl was added to the mix]

```
SELECT _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.entity_id, 
    _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.email, 
    customer_group.customer_group_code, 
    departments.`name`, 
    departments.manager, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.first_name, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_name, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_login_date, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_address, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_city, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_state, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_zip
FROM _n_cust_entity_storeid_15 INNER JOIN customer_group ON _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.group_id = customer_group.customer_group_id
     INNER JOIN departments ON _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.store_id = departments.store_id, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy
ORDER BY _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_name ASC
```

I've tried subqueries, joins, but just can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Schema  **Please** note that **entity_id** and **cust_id** fields would the be links between the **_ncust_rpt_copy table** and **the _n_cust_entity_storeid_15 tbl**
[image]

Comment: There are many records per store_id in the Departments table. You need to add some conditions to the query such that you only get one record. (Unless you want the email of each dept manager within the store).

Answer (score 1):

You have a `cross join` to the last table, `_n_cust_rpt_copy`:

```
SELECT _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.entity_id, 
    _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.email, 
    customer_group.customer_group_code, 
    departments.`name`, 
    departments.manager, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.first_name, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_name, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_login_date, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_address, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_city, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_state, 
    _n_cust_rpt_copy.billing_zip
FROM _n_cust_entity_storeid_15 INNER JOIN
     customer_group
     ON _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.group_id = customer_group.customer_group_id INNER JOIN
     departments
     ON _n_cust_entity_storeid_15.store_id = departments.store_id join
    _n_cust_rpt_copy
     ON ???
ORDER BY _n_cust_rpt_copy.last_name ASC;
```

It is not obvious to me what the right join conditions are, but there must be something.

I might guess they it at least includes the department:

```
   _n_cust_rpt_copy
     ON _n_cust_rpt_copy.department_name = departments.name and
```

Comment: sorry about that Gordon, I had gotten to the point, well still am at the point where I was trying everything.  An also, entity_id and cust_id are the same. I will make a note of that above, they would be joined.